# What is a vertical story?

Tags: meaning-in-context

https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/vertical_1?q=vertical+

> "What ties our vast history of interest in space exploration with the
>   current trends in education? The idea of finding a story that includes
>   failure and extensive testing. For safety reasons, space travel
>   requires continual testing for mechanical components to withstand
>   amazing amounts of pressure, temperature ranges and more. For our
>   current educational system and technology, similar to space launches,
>   students must go through an educational system that may not fully
>   prepare them for the rigors of a quickly-changing world. What role
>   does failure then play in a brand or **vertical story**? Let’s review
>   three ways in which failure can be positively built into the brand
>   narrative."

Source: https://www.forbes.com/sites/goldiechan/2019/07/11/successful-failure-3-reasons-why-brands-include-failure-in-storytelling/#111fa62f1732

Answer (score 1):

The interpretation could be as follows:

> "What role does failure then play in a (brand or vertical) story?"

where "vertical" means "A vertical market"
https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/vertical#Noun
https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/vertical_market

The author might be throwing around marketing buzzwords (like "vertical") to appear more esoteric.